# How to extract a common name from multipal filenames and delete something I don't want

Tags: python, text-extraction

For example, I have  7 files named:

```
g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt
g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt
```

I want to extract a name from these files, named as:

```
 g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0_MIX.txt
```

Any idea for this? Thanks.

Is there any possible that I can only depend on the underscores?

For example, separating filename as

```
"g18_84pp_2A_MVP2", "_", "GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG" "_", "MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX", ".txt".
```

Take `"g18_84pp_2A_MVP2"` without number `2`, take `"GoodiesT0"` from `"GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG"` and take first `"MIX"` from `"MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX"`, B/C I have a lot of files have different names for separating parts, I want it general as well

Comment: so basically drop any "column" that contains changing values, and keep only the "columns" that remain constant? Then why does CMVP*_Y1000 get dropped? what's special about those? And how does `2A` become `3A` in your result? Where does `HKJ-DFG` go? Voting to close, since your example makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I'v changed 3A to 2A already. The extracting name is what I want now.  CMVP*_Y1000 get dropped b/c it's the way I name filename, also HKJ - DFG I just don't need that. So any idea now? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
names = ['g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt']

f = lambda x: re.findall('g18_84pp_2A_MVP(.*?)_GoodiesT0(.*?)_MIX(.*?)\.txt', x)

for x in names:
    print(f(x))
```

Produces

```
[('1', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX')]
[('2', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX')]
[('3', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX')]
[('4', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX')]
[('5', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX')]
[('6', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX')]
[('7', '-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX')]
```

Filter the names that doesn't match this pattern:

```
names = list(filter(f, names))
```

Since it's unclear what you're trying to do, this is going to be a good starting point.

**UPDATE**

The question was updated. Here is what you (probably) want to achieve:

```
import re
names = ['g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt',
'g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt']

expression = 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP(.*?)_Goodies(.*?)_MIX(.*?)\.txt'
f = lambda x: re.findall(expression, x)
_f = lambda x: len(re.findall(expression, x))==3

for x in names:
    print(f(x))
```

Outputs

```
[('1', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX')]
[('2', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX')]
[('3', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX')]
[('4', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX')]
[('5', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX')]
[('6', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX')]
[('7', 'T0-HKJ-DFG', '-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX')]
```

If you need to filter the original list:

```
names = list(filter(_f, names))
```

Comment: Thank you. Very good approach. Is there any possible that I can only depend on the underscores? For example, separating filename as "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2", "_", "GoodiesT0", "-HKJ-DFG" "_", "MIX", "-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX", ".txt".    B/C I have a lot of files have different names for separating parts.

Comment: right, just want to take `"g18_84pp_2A_MVP2"` without number `2`, take `"GoodiesT0"` from `"GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG"` and take first `"MIX"` from `"MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX"`.

Comment: @crystalSo why `_f = lambda x: len(re.findall(expression, x))==3
` other values also give the same result.